# Layer-List drawable issue on Pre-Mashmallow

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have this drawable xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/timeLineRect" android:width="1dp" android:height="120dp" android:gravity="center"  >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/timeLineCircle"
    android:width="6dp" android:height="6dp" android:gravity="center" >
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
            android:topRightRadius="2dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="2dip"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

it draws this image

[image]

But on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M`

[image]

This image is visible

I have tried out setting size of gradientDrawables but nothing happens. I even tried intrinsicBounds but again no success. It works perfectly on Marshmallow devices.

`<item>` `android:height` and `android:width` was added in api 23. but there must be some workaround to generate it on previous versions.

Comment: if it was added in 23, it means that before 23 there was no such (or similar) feature

Comment: why wont you use a nine-patch-drawable or a custom `Shape` class?

Comment: i can use the png which i have shared but i want to know this would have been achived with layed list. there ought to be some procedure to do it cleanly. :)